# SqlClient codes that return number of row affected

Tags: c#

The codes below is in DLL.

Here's the problems that I can identify:

1) Caller won't know what's the exception?

2) Catch exception 1 but throw exception 2.

3) `num` is not sum but overwrite.

What else?

These codes are in production, I just found it not well written.

I would like to get more feedback and is there any other way to improve it?

```
public int ExecuteTransactionBatchSQL(ref string[] arrSqlStatement)
{
  int num = -1;
  this.myCn = new SqlConnection(this._ConnectionString);
  SqlTransaction sqlTransaction = (SqlTransaction) null;
  try
  {
    this.myCn.Open();
    sqlTransaction = this.myCn.BeginTransaction("MyTransaction");
    this.myCmd = new SqlCommand();
    this.myCmd.Connection = this.myCn;
    this.myCmd.Transaction = sqlTransaction;
    for (int index = 0; index < arrSqlStatement.Length && (arrSqlStatement[index] != null && string.Compare(arrSqlStatement[index], string.Empty) != 0); ++index)
    {
      this.myCmd.CommandText = arrSqlStatement[index];
      num = this.myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    sqlTransaction.Commit();
  }
  catch (Exception ex1)
  {
    num = -1;
    try
    {
      if (sqlTransaction != null)
        ((DbTransaction) sqlTransaction).Rollback();
    }
    catch (Exception ex2)
    {
      throw ex2;
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    if (this.myCmd != null)
      this.myCmd.Dispose();
    if (this.myCn != null)
      this.myCn.Close();
  }
  return num;
}
```

Comment: Did you write or do you have to maintain this code ?

Comment: maintain, it drive me crazy.

Comment: If you're sure it's working, then you don't need an uncertain title as such. Only have it state the code's purpose.

Comment: Your language is a little unclear, but are you saying you've identified those problems. And now you'd like to get more feedback on those and other ways you could improve this code?

Comment: Yes. I thought those are implied on code review.

Answer (score 1):

- `SqlConnection`, `SqlTransaction` and `SqlCommand` are implementing the `IDispoable` interface and should therefor be enclosed in a `using` statement. This makes sure that the objects are properly disposed.
- why is the `string[] arrSqlStatement` passed with the `ref` keyword ?
- this condition `(arrSqlStatement[index] != null && string.Compare(arrSqlStatement[index], string.Empty) != 0)` in the loops header makes the code almost unreadable. A much better way would be to use the built in string method [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but much better would be to first filter these invalid statements by using a `linq` query.
- I assume that on the callers side there will be some kind of exception handling so I would skip this whole `try..catch`'s. You can't handle the exception, so there is no need for it. Having a return of `num = -1` doesn't have enough value that these `try..catch`'s should be there.
- The reuse of class owned objects like `this.myCn` and `this.myCmd` will make your code in this case non thread safe if the object is passed to several other objects. Creating new objects in the method itself is much better.

Applying these points will lead to

```
public int ExecuteTransactionBatchSQL(ref string[] arrSqlStatement)
{
    IEnumerable<string> sqlStatements = arrSqlStatement.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s));

    if (!sqlStatements.Any()) { return -1; }

    int num = -1;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this._ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlTransaction sqlTransaction = connection.BeginTransaction("MyTransaction"))
        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand() { Connection = connection, Transaction = sqlTransaction })
        {
            foreach(string statement in sqlStatements)
            {
                sqlCommand.CommandText = statement;
                num = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            sqlTransaction.Commit();

        }
    }

    return num;
}
```